# Android ContentProvider URI format for select queries not on _id

Tags: android, rest, android-contentprovider

I am trying to understand Android REST-style ContentProvider URIs.  Assume that I have a database of messages, each of which has an "_id" and "recipient" field (among others).

I understand how to get all columns of all messages:

```
// Get all messages.
URI uri = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/messages");
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
```

I understand how to get the message with an _id of 1:

```
// Get the message with _id 1.
URI uri = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/messages/1");
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
```

What if I want to get the messages with a recipient value of foo@bar.com?

```
// Get the messages with recipient "foo@bar.com"
URI uri = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + ??);  // What goes here?
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, 
    "recipient = ?", "foo@bar.com", null);
```

I'd be happy to pass the recipient value in the URI if that's better style:

```
// Get the messages with recipient "foo@bar.com"/
URI uri = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + ?? + "foo@bar.com");  // What goes here?
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
```

For this last use case, what is the preferred URI format?

**Update**: I am the author of both the ContentProvider and the client, so I can use whatever format I want.  I would still like to know what's considered the best practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In this last case, what should go after the AUTHORITY in the URI?

Whatever you want. If you are writing the `ContentProvider`, it is up to you to define what your `Uri` syntax means, for the path segments to the right of the authority.

In your case, you are passing the value (`foo@bar.com`) via query parameters. Hence, your `??` can be:

- nothing at all
- some path segment that helps you identify what sort of table you are querying, like `messages`
- `asrasiojdflkasdjkl90238490qa89dsfjlas` or some other random string
- etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply (and your great book).  I know I can make them whatever I want, but I'd like to know what I should make them.  (I've updated my question.)  I'm happy to pass them in the URI instead of in an argument if that's more idiomatic.

Comment: @espertus: I'd argue that `messages` is the idiomatic one. `messages` represents the collection of messages you are querying against; `messages/1` represents a single message of interest.